# Deadlock when combining Python with TBB

Tags: python, python-3.x, tbb, pybind11

[Here](https://github.com/dmikushin/python_tbb) I would like to offer a complete test case showing a simple TBB `parallel_for` construct causing deadlock in a Python application. Python frontend is combined with TBB backend using pybind11:

```
void backend_tbb(vector<int>& result, std::function<int (int)>& callback)
{
    int nthreads = tbb::task_scheduler_init::default_num_threads();
    const char* cnthreads = getenv("TBB_NUM_THREADS");
    if (cnthreads) nthreads = std::max(1, atoi(cnthreads));

    tbb::task_group group;
    tbb::task_arena arena(nthreads, 1);
    tbb::task_scheduler_init init(nthreads);

    group.run( [&] {
        tbb::parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, result.size()),
            [&](const tbb::blocked_range<int>& range)
        {
            for (int i = range.begin(); i != range.end(); i++)
                result[i] = callback(i);
        });
    });

    arena.execute( [&] { group.wait(); });      
}

void backend_serial(vector<int>& result, std::function<int (int)>& callback)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
        result[i] = callback(i);
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(python_tbb, m)
{
    pybind11::bind_vector<std::vector<int> >(m, "stdvectorint");

    m.def("backend_tbb", &backend_tbb, "TBB backend");
    m.def("backend_serial", &backend_serial, "Serial backend");
}
```

With `backend_tbb` uncommented, app deadlocks infinitely:

```
from python_tbb import *
import numpy as np

def callback(a) :
    return int(a) * 10

def main() :
    length = 10
    result1 = stdvectorint(np.zeros(length, np.int32))
    result2 = stdvectorint(np.zeros(length, np.int32))

    backend_serial(result1, callback)
        # XXX Uncomment this to get the program hang
    #backend_tbb(result2, callback)

    for i in range(length) :
        print("%d vs %d" % (result1[i], result2[i]))

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

I've tried `gil_scoped_acquire/gil_scoped_release`, but no change. [Similar solution](https://gist.github.com/zed/3471699/6c2d6ac9f53a279a9ac66a95a73ad43805feb73c) reportedly works for OpenMP loop - but again no luck when I try to do the same for TBB. Please kindly advice on this case, thanks!

Comment: You can read [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506144) that `tbb::blocked_range [i, j)` does not guarantee `j>=i`. Can you try replacing `i != range.end()` with `i < range.end()`? Maybe you're running an infinite loop there. Even if not, that's definitely a hazard.

Comment: Actually [intel compares the same way you do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59910185/deadlock-when-combining-python-with-tbb) so that's not the answer. Can't help you, sorry...

Comment: @Nearoo the loop should be OK, works for single-threaded case

Comment: Of course, in the single threaded case `j>i` is always true. But since intel does it the same way, it's indeed unlikely that this is the problem. However your argument makes me think you don't fully understand what your code does. Are you sure it's a deadlock at all? Do you use a debugger?

Comment: @Nearoo, please follow the link to GitHub - there you can find a complete test case and examine your suggestions: https://github.com/dmikushin/python_tbb

Comment: That's very forthcoming for you, but you may kindly test your code yourself.

Comment: Also, your repo literally only contains what you've posted here. I've flagged your question as in need of details, as you clearly don't understand what my suggestion does and likely don't know what you're doing at all

Comment: Dear @Nearoo I made this repo specifically to test this issue (minimal testcase). Thank you for your comments, I hope you will stop them now and let others to make more useful input.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that TBB tasks get spawned inside `task_arena` instance associated with the `task_group`, but the waiting is done inside another `task_arena` instance, called `arena`. This can lead to the deadlock. To fix the issue, try wrapping the call to `group.run()` into `task_arena.execute()` similarly as it is done for `group.wait()`.

However, in this case, the latter wrapping seems superfluous. So, you might want to combine two wrappings into one

```cpp
arena.execute() {
   group.run( /* ... */ );
   group.wait();
}
```

which, in this particular example, makes the use of `task_group` unnecessary since the master thread spawns the tasks and immediately joins for participating in their execution, similarly as it is done in `tbb::parallel_for`. Thus, `task_group` can be merely removed.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! The reason I wanted to have `run` and `wait` is separate `execute` clauses is asynchrony. That is, some other code should be between them on line 35.

Comment: Unfortunately, reopening, as is certain conditions the test still hangs, even with all previous issues fixed. Please find the updated code on GitHub: https://github.com/dmikushin/python_tbb

Comment: @DmitryMikushin, I have tried the C++ part in online IDE. It passes. Please take a look: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ffa51c6611aa46e3

This means that likely something is wrong in the intermediate layer, that is between Python and C++. Unfortunately, I am not a Python expert (at least yet).

Comment: Of course, TBB works by itself. Yes, it only makes sense in a combination with Python.

Comment: As I'm starting to understand the TBB internals, it seems that the required change is a kind of following: each time a TBB thread goes on `pause`, it should release Python GIL. Currently, as long as GIL is not released, the paused TBB thread keeps others from doing anything.

Comment: I would not say it (meaning TBB) should release Python GIL. I would say Python GIL (read any synchronization primitive) should be released whenever TBB is called (read a call to the user code/another component is made).